# Jpeg compression artefact (green pixel)

Tags: compression, jpeg, quantization

I'm programming an artisanal jpeg algorithm. However, the quantization step seems to be problematic :
Here is the picture i'm trying to encode : [Lena.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnHVb.png)

And here is the result just after the quantization step (+decoding but without the huffman encoding stuff) : [post quantization result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03ZVO.png)

Now my code for this step :

```
def quantification(transformee) :
matrice=np.array([(16 , 11 , 10 , 16 , 24 , 40 , 51 , 61 ),(12 , 12 , 14 , 19 , 26 , 58 , 60 , 55 ),(14 , 13 , 16 , 24 , 40 , 57 , 69 , 56 ),(14 , 17 , 22 , 29 , 51 , 87 , 80 , 62 ),(18 , 22 , 37 , 56 , 68 , 109 , 103 , 77 ),(24 , 35 , 55 , 64 , 81 , 104 , 113 , 92 ),(49 , 64 , 78 , 87 , 103 , 121 , 120 , 101 ),( 72 , 92 , 95 , 98 , 112 , 100 , 103 , 99)],dtype=float)
quanti=[]
for i in transformee :
    k=i/matrice
    quanti+=[np.around(k)]
return quanti

def dequantification(quanti) :
matrice=np.array([(16 , 11 , 10 , 16 , 24 , 40 , 51 , 61 ),(12 , 12 , 14 , 19 , 26 , 58 , 60 , 55 ),(14 , 13 , 16 , 24 , 40 , 57 , 69 , 56 ),(14 , 17 , 22 , 29 , 51 , 87 , 80 , 62 ),(18 , 22 , 37 , 56 , 68 , 109 , 103 , 77 ),(24 , 35 , 55 , 64 , 81 , 104 , 113 , 92 ),(49 , 64 , 78 , 87 , 103 , 121 , 120 , 101 ),( 72 , 92 , 95 , 98 , 112 , 100 , 103 , 99)],dtype=float)
retour_transformee=[]
for k in quanti :
    temp=np.zeros((8,8),dtype=float)
    for i in range(8) :
        for j in range(8) :
            temp[i,j]=matrice[i,j]*k[i,j]
    retour_transformee.append(temp)
return retour_transformee
```

transformee is a list of 8*8 matrix (DCT is already used).
The quantization matrix is the one given in wikipedia (JPEG)

Sorry for the french part in the algorithm

Comment: You mentioned you fixed this issue in a comment. Can you remember what the issue was? I have a similar issue. :/

Answer (score 0):

The image looks like you're not clipping values after decoding.

DCT coefficients changed by quantization may result in IDCT producing values outside of the 0-255 range.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i did correct my algorithm. However, I have made a test on the IDCT result : all the coefficient are between 0 and 255 ([[-128:+127]] to center the values on 0). Same on the final picture.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest ensuring that your RGB to YCbCr and YCbCr to RGB conversions ensure that you are clamped to [0..255]. The two color spaces overlap but are not identical.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try it